# Were there any other serious contenders for the role of Mr. Wednesday?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, actors, american-gods

When I read the book, I imagined Mr. Wednesday looking quite different from Ian McShane, the actor who plays him in the TV episodes - more wolf-like, leaner, a tad smoother, suave-like, sort of. McShane to me brings out more of the con man in Wednesday, rather than the grim old god so far (only seen the first episodes).

Still, I very much like McShane in the role, however, I am interested in whether there were any other serious contenders for the role and who they were?

I only was able to find that Nicholas Cage was considered, and from what I have seen of Cage, I would agree that McShane is a far greater fit for the role (and possibly a greater actor, but that is of course, even more open to different opinion).

Comment: You should see how he's portrayed in the comic adaptation: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/486526/Previews/8435652df298502de1fafa6b1d1872ba._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg

Comment: Fun fact: McShane was first [asked to play Czernobog](http://neil-gaiman.tumblr.com/post/148020727121/hello-mr-gaiman-just-like-half-of-the-internet).

Comment: Wednesday was also apparently [inspired by Rip Torn](http://neil-gaiman.tumblr.com/post/103182431206/i-was-wondering-if-you-ever-tend-to-envision-an).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to think of whom I was picturing as more Mr.Wednesday from my imagination and after giving it some thought I now think I had  in mind someone like Michael Douglas (as of Wall Street 2) with a touch of Christopher Walken.

Comment: My original book-imagery-headcanon was Hammond from Jurassic Park, at least in the early part of the flick where he's the old man enjoying knowing exactly what's going on while everyone else is confused.  I don't know why, I've never seen that actor do any true bastard role, but it's hard to argue with my head.

Comment: I'm curious why this is attracting close votes as *primarily opinion based*. If the close voters could leave a comment, I'd be curious in knowing what your reasoning is.

Comment: I could see, perhaps BRIAN BLESSED in that role. Would make up for not getting to be Odin in the MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Cage claimed to have been more than just seriously considered.  He says the offered him the part, but he turned it down.  In to [this *L.A. Times* interview](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-nicolas-cage-army-of-one-20161028-story.html), Cage said:

> You know, it's a good point and I've been invited many times to go on a show, one of which was on Neil Gaiman's “American Gods” to play Mr. Wednesday, which was a great part, beautifully written. And I said no.